# Is it possible to align vertically in Ext.grid.column.Action

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action

Using an extjs action column I'm able to centre horizontally an icon for the action column, however I'm unable to vertically align the icon, which leads to an odd looking layout.

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            tooltip: this.self.QUICKLOOK_TOOLTIP,
            tdCls: 'action-column',
            isDisabled: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, record) {
                return !this.quicklookable(record);
            },
            getClass: function(value, metaData, record) {
                return this.quicklookable(record) ? 'bui-icon quicklook' : '';
            },
            itemId: 'activityListOpenQuicklook',
            width: 50,
            align: 'center',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, evt, record, row) {
                this.fireEvent('openQuicklook', record);
            },
            scope: this
}
```

Does anyone have a solution on how to vertically align using the action column component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to add `vertical-align: middle;` to your CSS, like so:

```
.x-grid-cell.action-column {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Forgot this was still open, thanks for getting back to me. Yes that would do it, but it would over-write the way all ext grids behave. Better to add an external cls with a !important flag to override the ext base css

Comment: There is no need for `!important` flag in this case. If you want it only in action column of specific grids, you can always just use `.specific-grid-class .x-grid-cell.action-column` selector.